# DevExpress GridControl Unbound Columns

Tags: gridview, devexpress, gridcontrol

I would like to know how to properly add a unbound column into a gridview.
I've added a unbound column in the designer (set the unbound type, display format and all)
but whenever I run the application, try to change the value of the unbound column and loses its focus the value is not saved (even the display format is not displaying correctly when I'm changing it).

I must be doing something wrong. I need help guys!

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unbound column does not provide a storage to save its values.  Instead, the GridView publishes the [CustomUnboundColumnData](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CustomUnboundColumnDatatopic) event which can be used to provide data to the unbound column and also save it.  The help topic contains the example of how to use this event.  Also, you will find a lot of useful information abound unbound columns at:

[Unbound Columns](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1477)

Comment: Ive had this very same question for about a year, and this answer pointed me in the right direction. Thank you!
All I had to do is to check in this event if it was the column I was looking for, and then check if it was getting or setting data. From that point all I had to do was to handle it properly.