# Add a column and show total in grid control in ax POS form

Tags: visual-studio-2013, devexpress, axapta

I am using *Devexpress* to customize **AX POS** 
Open POS >> Cashier Tasks >> Picking and Receiving >> TransferIN / TransferOut
Here I need to add a new column in gvInventory named colDifference which shows difference of orderedQty-Received
Also I need to show Total of diffQty at Bottom of gridView[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to add a new column in gvInventory named colDifference which
>   shows difference of orderedQty-Received?

I suggest you to create an [Unbound Column](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1477) in GridView and then calculate your difference at [ColumnView.CustomUnboundColumnData](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CustomUnboundColumnDatatopic) event. See below example code snippet:

```
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base;
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid;
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
   // ...
   gridControl1.ForceInitialize();

   // Create an unbound column.
   GridColumn unbColumn = gridView1.Columns.AddField("Total");
   unbColumn.VisibleIndex = gridView1.Columns.Count;
   unbColumn.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.Decimal;
   // Disable editing.
   unbColumn.OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = false;
   // Specify format settings.
   unbColumn.DisplayFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.Numeric;
   unbColumn.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "c";
   // Customize the appearance settings.
   unbColumn.AppearanceCell.BackColor = Color.LemonChiffon;
}

// Returns the total amount for a specific row.
decimal getTotalValue(GridView view, int listSourceRowIndex) {
    decimal unitPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(view.GetListSourceRowCellValue(listSourceRowIndex, "UnitPrice"));
    decimal quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(view.GetListSourceRowCellValue(listSourceRowIndex, "Quantity"));
    decimal discount = Convert.ToDecimal(view.GetListSourceRowCellValue(listSourceRowIndex, "Discount"));
    return unitPrice * quantity * (1 - discount);
}

// Provides data for the Total column.
private void gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData(object sender, CustomColumnDataEventArgs e) {
   GridView view = sender as GridView;
   if (e.Column.FieldName == "Total" && e.IsGetData) e.Value = 
     getTotalValue(view, e.ListSourceRowIndex);
}
```

References:
[How to create and populate an unbound column](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3354)
[DevExpress GridControl Unbound Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432940/devexpress-gridcontrol-unbound-columns)

> To show Total of diffQty at Bottom of gridView

**Source:** [Total Summary](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument699)
*The [GridColumn.SummaryItem](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsGridColumn_SummaryItemtopic.aspx) property is a GridSummaryItem object, which allows you to set the field against the values the summary has calculated, the aggregate function applied to field values and the summary value format. The image below shows how to customize the column summary type and display format via the `GridSummaryItem.SummaryType` and `GridSummaryItem.DisplayFormat` properties respectively.*

example:

```
colUnitsInStock1.SummaryItem.SummaryType = DevExpress.Data.SummaryItemType.Sum;
colUnitsInStock1.SummaryItem.DisplayFormat = "Sum= {0:n2}";
```

To know more go through  [Summaries Overview](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/CustomDocument997.aspx) topic.

Comment: I did this by using Run Designer Option